# How to group mongodb count results by regular expresions?

Tags: regex, mongodb

I have a small database in which I stored some tweets and I'm trying to find out which was the most popular keyword from a previously selected set of words.

The structure of the documents is:

```
{
     "Username": status.author.screen_name,
     "Tweet": status.text,
     "Retweets": status.retweet_count,
     "Favorites": status.favorite_count,
     "Followers": status.user.followers_count,
     "Background-Color": status.user.profile_background_color,
     "Date-Created": status.user.created_at,
     "Location": status.user.location,
     "Verified-Status": status.user.verified,
     "Geo-Enabled": status.user.geo_enabled,
     "Possibly-Sensitive": status.user.geo_enabled
}
```

and the results are based on the Tweet field

I've already made individual queries with regular expressions finding how many times each word appears, but I haven't figured out a way to get some output like:

```
{ 
     Keyword: "something",
     Count: 1200,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mongodb aggregate function to filter and group to get the count.